# sphinx-doc documentation on readthedocs.org depends on private sphinxcontrib-package

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I host a sphinx-doc website on readthedocs.org which depends on a private sphinx-doc extension/sphinxcontrib-package [extension_name]. On my local pc this extension is located in the subdirectory [sphinx-doc project root]/exts/sphinxcontrib-[extension name] and "referenced" in **conf.py** with

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('exts/sphinxcontrib-<extension name>/sphinxcontrib'))

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.graphviz',
    '[extension name]'
]
```

The .py file is located in the "source" directory *sphinxcontrib*. The local sphinx-doc build output is as expected. However the build on readthedocs.org fails due to an

```
ImportError: No module named 'sphinxcontrib'
...
Extension error:
Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.p3 (exception: No module named 'sphinxcontrib')
```

As the extension is in beta phase i do not want to distribute it online. (If i would do so i should be able to install it as readthedocs.org pre-build from the web source i guess.) How can i handle this issue?

Comment: This is in response to your last Q&A and it it came off like it was spam.  here is a little guidline about that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion